# Datatables not showing

Tags: javascript, datatables

I'm trying to get datatables to work.

These are the files i'm including :

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="/js/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.7/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<link href="/css/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet">

<link href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

This is the function i call:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#takentabel').dataTable();
    });
```

error i get:

```
today:82 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).dataTable is not a function
at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (today:82)
at c (jquery-1.10.2.min.js:4)
at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-1.10.2.min.js:4)
at Function.ready (jquery-1.10.2.min.js:4)
at HTMLDocument.q (jquery-1.10.2.min.js:4)
```

Thanks,
Mario

Comment: This seems problem with jquery version, try with latest one.

Comment: Is it camel case `$().dataTable` or capital case `$().DataTable`?

Comment: @LessQuesar i tried both. No other errors pop up if i change that.
I tried getting a newer version of jquery with no result

Comment: have you tried to refresh page by clear cache (Ctrl + F5)?

Comment: Yes. This still does not give any results, same error :\

Comment: There's something going on that you're not telling us, as I can create a jsfiddle with the code you provided(I added the HTML table code) and it works fine. (https://jsfiddle.net/markps/m41uc66L/)[https://jsfiddle.net/markps/m41uc66L/]

Comment: The only thing i can think of is that i'm using laravel, but i thought that wouldn't matter as other scripts seems to be working correctly? @markpsmith

Comment: The error points to an issue with the order in which the scripts are loaded, I have no idea whether Laravel would affect that.  Can you confirm that jquery is loaded before datatables? (ie look in the browser's web developer console)

Comment: I fixed it by adding a thead and tbody to the table, which i forgot :/